# pivot table form that allows entry

Tags: ms-access, subtotal

[FormExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKeXE.png)I have searched high and low and it seems that the answer is I can't do it, but I thought I would check with some experts before I give up.  I have a financial database that captures investments.  Each department inputs a list of investments they would like with an idea of how much it costs (this is the "Submit" field).  Then the investments office puts all these requests together, bounces it against money provided and decides a "Proposed" amount.  There is then a meeting where the "Approved" amount is decided.  I have a pivot table form that is providing exactly (although ugly) what I need, a subtotal for each department's "Submit", "Proposed", and "Approved".  The problem is the user can't change this form (e.g., enter the "Proposed" or "Approved" amount).  I tried creating a continuous form (due to the department's not being static), but I can't figure out how (from research I don't think this is possible) to group and subtotal by Department.  I tried creating a subform (what is usually suggested in the posts I have read thus far) but then Access tells me a continuous form cannot contain a subform.
This is two tables, the Project Detail Table (where Department and Project Title is pulled from) which has a one-to-may relationship with the Project Budget table; each Project can have several budget items due to the "color" of money.  In this instance however, only one type of money is being looked at so it is a one-to-one relationship, not sure if that helps me out at all though.
I am pretty strong with VBA, maybe adding a control with the subtotal formula and then loop through the records on load and hide all but the last one?
Thanks in Advance,
Jessica

Comment: Can you post examples of your tables and the result you expect?

Comment: I put an example of what the form should look like, the tables are pretty straight forward, tblProjectDetail has the fields of title, BenefittingDept, FundManagerCode, FSP, and Priority while tblProjectBudget has Project as a foreign key with the Submit (called Requirement on the form), Proposed (labeled 'Discussion Starter'), and Approved (labeled 'Final Result') amounts.  Thank you!

Comment: OK, I am going with it is not possible.  So, I created a form with two subforms, one subform contains the continuous form that I was trying to add the subtotals to and another subform that is also a continuous form with "SELECT Distinct Department FROM tblProjectDetail" as its recordsource and I am putting the subtotals in there.  Hopefully this format will work for my customer.